# Order Statistics Sum

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Hey can anyone please help me with this.

Find the probability that range of a random sample of size 4 from $U(0,1)$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

i.e  to find $ \mathbb{P}(Y_{4}-Y_{1})< 1/2$ where $Y_n$ is the nth order statistic.

An approach is to first get the joint distribution, then do the bivariate transformation and finally integrate but I am unable to solve it, Would really appreciate help.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think it's something like this... assuming each of the $X_i$'s are iid and $Uniform(0,1)$ the joint density function of the range is, 

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x_1,x_n) = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} [F(x_n)-F(x_1)]^{n-2}f(x_1)f(x_n) =\frac{4!}{2!} (x_4 - x_1)^2 \, dx_1 dx_4 $$ $$P(X_4 - X_1 < 0.5) =  \int \int_{x_4-x_1 < 0.5} 12(x_4 - x_1)^2 \, dx_1 dx_4 $$

Comment: You asked the same question in another post. Please keep any one of them. You could edit your post to add details.

Comment: This is correct up till this point. Can you help me to solve the integral please. That is the part I am stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution of the $n+1$ intervals formed by $n$ points uniformly randomly chosen in an interval is invariant under permutations of the intervals. In particular, the joint distribution of the first and last intervals is the same as the joint distribution of the first and second intervals. (This can be seen by uniformly randomly choosing $n+1$ points on a circle, then uniformly randomly choosing one of the points as the point at which to cut the circle into an interval; this demonstrates the equivalence of the $n+1$ intervals formed by the $n$ points.)

Thus, the probability that the first and last interval together are greater than $\frac12$ is the probability that the first and second interval together are greater than $\frac12$, which is the probability that at most one of the $4$ points lies in the first half of $[0,1]$. This is

$$
\left(\frac12\right)^4+\binom41\left(\frac12\right)^4=\frac5{16}\;.
$$

Comment: Wow very slick!

Comment: @HJ_beginner: This is a "trick" well worth remembering; it significantly simplifies very many calculations involving uniformly randomly chosen points in an interval or linear arrangements of balls. To give just one more example, it follows immediately that the expectation of the $k$-th order statistic of $n$ points uniformly randomly chosen in the unit interval is $\frac k{n+1}$, and that the expectation of the position of the $k$-th red ball out of $n$ red balls among $m$ balls in a line is $(m+1)\frac k{n+1}$.

Comment: Very useful... I will do my best to keep this in mind, so one day I can look clever in front of someone, ideally a cute girl, and then she's so impressed she falls in love with me haha.