# Order Statistics Bivariate transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Hey can anyone please help me with this.

Find the probability range that a random sample of size $4$ from $U(0,1)$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

I.e find $P\left(y_4-y_1<\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where $y$ is the $n^{th}$ order statistic.

The way this is approached is first get the joint distribution, then do the bivariate transformation and finally integrate. I have the solution but I am unable to understand how the bivariate bounds are reached as shown in image 2. please help

[image: Fist page of solution]

[image: Second page]

Comment: Same question asked again:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905211/order-statistics-sum

Comment: Well I don't know what people would prefer to reply to: a un answered question or explain an existing solution so I made two posts. I am specifically asking how the integral bounds are reached in this one while the other is general.

Comment: Both of your posts are unanswered. This one has context since you have shown your work; the other post doesn't. I was suggesting you delete the other post altogether and keep this one. Your actual question is same, so both posts are duplicates of each other.

Comment: @RahulDeora in regards to your notes, it seems like to solve the following (below) you're doing the Jacobian thing (which I believe is good for finding the joint distribution function of functions of RVs...) but it seems to me Jacobians and all that is not needed to calculate the below, you just solve it like "any other" double integral. 

$$P(X_4 - X_1 < 0.5) =  \int \int_{x_4-x_1 < 0.5} 12(x_4 - x_1)^2 \, dx_1 dx_4$$

I would post an answer but I am a beginner and don't want to lead you astray.